# Sharepoint 2010 error after uploading files do share document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After uploading folder using standard sharepoint web interface I am unable to get into my site. How to remove docs I added from sql server (no backup...) ?

```
<nativehr>0x80020009</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x80020009</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[COMException (0x80020009): <nativehr>0x80020009</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) +256

[SPException]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +27268514
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) +27652822
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData() +4145
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count() +42
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(String strId, Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId, String strViewFields, Boolean bDatesInUtc) +493
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_Item() +1242
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_Fields() +16
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FieldMetadata.get_Field() +102
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FormField.CreateChildControls() +123
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +531
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

and log file

High        0x80020009  1e32b7dc-c520-4521-b5f8-dc260d60a980
08/17/2011 12:50:31.67  w3wp.exe (0x5144)                           0x2558  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:  [Managed code transition]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback p... 1e32b7dc-c520-4521-b5f8-dc260d60a980
08/17/2011 12:50:31.67* w3wp.exe (0x5144)                           0x2558  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...PagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)    1e32b7dc-c520-4521-b5f8-dc260d60a980
08/17/2011 12:50:31.67  w3wp.exe (0x5144)                           0x2558  SharePoint Foundation           Template Cache                  fo1v    Monitorable Leaked record detected with address 0000000005C40188, name (unknown), and thread local refcount 1.  1e32b7dc-c520-4521-b5f8-dc260d60a980
08/17/2011 12:50:31.67  w3wp.exe (0x5144)                           0x2558  SharePoint Foundation           Template Cache                  fo1w    High        AddRef stack 1 for record with address 0000000005C40188: owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000000CBA0) at 0x000007FEED0ACBA0 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000002788D) at 0x000007FEED0C788D mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002D04C7) at 0x000007FEF43B04C7 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000010C8D9) at 0x000007FEF734C8D9 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001A46D40) at 0x000007FED3686D40 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001B81601) at 0x000007FED37C1601 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001B84A1A) at 0x000007FED37C4A1A Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=... 1e32b7dc-c520-4521-b5f8-dc260d60a980
08/17/2011 12:50:31.67* w3wp.exe (0x5144)                           0x2558  SharePoint Foundation           Template Cache                  fo1w    High        ...0000000001B338CD) at 0x000007FED37738CD Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001BB06AA) at 0x000007FED37F06AA Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001BAF3D0) at 0x000007FED37EF3D0 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000002239D66) at 0x000007FED3E79D66 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000223A7AB) at 0x000007FED3E7A7AB System.Web.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000029E912) at 0x000007FEE7A7E912 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000207B173) at 0x000007FED3CBB173 System.Web.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000029D552) at 0x000007FEE7A7D552 System.Web.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000...  1e32b7dc-c520-4521-b5f8-dc260d60a980
08/17/2011 12:50:31.67* w3wp.exe (0x5144)                           0x2558  SharePoint Foundation           Template Cache                  fo1w